# Create an array for NewDirectByteBuffer?

Tags: java, arrays, java-native-interface, buffer

Here is my code

JNI code

```
jobject jArray = jEnv->NewDirectByteBuffer(data, len);
```

JAVA code

```
ByteBuffer byteBuf = jni function call;
System.out.printf("isArray : %b", byteBuf.isArray());
byte[] bytes = byteBuf.array();
```

The printing shows isArray is false. And an exception was thrown on the line byteBuf.array().
Is it possible to create an array for that NewDirected buffer for JAVA access?

Comment: You have to decide. Do you want a *direct* buffer or an *array based* buffer? In the latter case, why don’t you just invoke [`ByteBuffer.allocate(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocate(int))?

Comment: The buffer pointed by data was allocated from c++ and I wished to create an byte array for java to access. Since the buffer was quite large so that I wondered a zero-copy method.

Comment: Then just use `byteBuf.get(i)` and `byteBuf.put(i, b)` instead of `bytes[i]` and `bytes[i] = b`.